# Evolution MAPI & Evo EWS not working in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: dns, evolution, evolution-mapi

I recently upgraded my laptop from 12.04 LTS to 14.04 LTS without problems. First thing I tried is to reconnect Evo to our company's Exchange server. I installed evo-mapi and the evo-ews package and tried to connect to the exchange server by using ews and mapi. In both cases I receive the error, that evo cannot resolve a hostname. In the case of EWS  I receive the error, that the server running the EWS service cannot be found:

```
[ raptor ] /var/crash > EWS_DEBUG=2 evolution

 (evolution:5257): camel-WARNING **: Failed to initialize NSS SQL database in sql:/etc/pki/nssdb: NSS error -8187
sh: 1: /usr/lib/nspluginwrapper/i386/linux/npviewer: not found
sh: 1: /usr/lib/nspluginwrapper/i386/linux/npviewer: not found
*** NSPlugin Wrapper *** ERROR: failed to execute NSPlugin viewer
< HTTP/1.1 2 Cannot resolve hostname (myserver.mydomain.com)
< Soup-Debug-Timestamp: 1408604840
< Soup-Debug: ESoapMessage 0 (0x7fe051025db0)
```

(Changed the server name above...)

In the case of MAPI I receive the (very strange) error: "Error resolving 'http': Name or service not known" the moment I try to authenticate (either basic or Kerberos - that makes no difference).

I tried nslookup/dig to resolve the hostnames I specified in the configuration. This worked like a charm - so basically the resolver seems to work.

My /etc/hosts file looks like this:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   raptor raptor.lenze.com
# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

The `/etc/nsswitch.conf` hosts line:

```
 hosts:          files dns
```

I deleted some (I think) M$ related stuff from this line.

Any idea how to resolve this problem ? I'm sure I'm doing something wrong ... At least MAPI worked in 12.04 (more or less).

Answer (score 1):

I dug somewhat deeper into this problem and finally I got the MAPI working again.

As I wrote above evo tried to connect to a host named 'http' - at least, it complained, that the hostname could not be resolved. I captured some packages by using tcpdump and indeed: evo (or the MAPI plugin) asks for the host 'http'. So finally I decided to add an entry to `/etc/hosts`:

```
uuu.vvv.www.xxx http http.domain.com
```

I pointed this entry to the server running the EWS & autoconfiguration service - I'm not an Exchange specialist, I'm not sure, what this server is used for in in the Exchange environment. It seems to be something like a load balancer.

Anyway: adding this server helped. I was able to authenticate and the MAPI account was created within Evolution.

After account creation I changed `/etc/hosts` again and pointed the host 'http' to a normal linux server. The MAPI account still works with this entry. So it seems, that evo just needs  to be able to resolve the host. If you delete the entry, evo throws and error, that the host 'http' cannot be resolved.